# How to convert ArrayList of Strings to ints, so they can be added?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to convert each `String` in an `ArrayList` to `int` so then I can add them,

`asuma` is an `ArrayList` containing `String`

I need to iterate over this `ArrayList` to convert `String` to `int`

```
for (int i = 0; i <=asuma.size(); i++) {
```

and then I need to add the integers. How do I do it?

Comment: Provide more information, context

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What error do you get?

Comment: `i` is an `int` already, no need to parse it

Comment: Can you provide your your array list format?

Comment: Question is not a "code is not working" but a "how do I do" question. Therefore it should be reopened. And the OP should learn a bit more about Java programming. This should be part of a fairly standard course in Java.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the ArrayList you are referring to is `asuma` and that it is an `ArrayList<String>`.  In that case, you can do this:

```
for (String s : asuma) {
    int valorFinal = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u try that:

```
for (int i = 0; i <=asuma.size(); i++) {
    int valorFinal = Integer.parseInt(asuma.get(i));
}
```